# Laravel broadcasting with pusher Error : (Uncaught Options object must provide a cluster)

Tags: laravel, echo, pusher

I've been trying to set up my a broadcast system with pusher and followed the documentation step by step. When I start the server I get an error,

> "Uncaught Options object must provide a cluster"

in my console.

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',

            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

So I checked my options object in the broadcast configuration and I noticed my configuration doesn't have a cluster option, so I added it manually, but still have that error.

#### File *.env*

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=1529400
PUSHER_APP_KEY=521a8d3a78ab50e2c14d
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=ce93e12b5f74f8280624
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
e here
```

#### File *broadcast.php*

````php
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```
````

Answer (score 14):

I encountered the same error and solved it by adding `cluster` to the parameters that are passed in the new Echo instance:
`bootstrap.js:`

added `cluster:import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,`

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    disableStats: true,
    cluster:import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,//added this line
});
```

Also, make sure that it is added in the `broadcasting.php` in the options array:

```
 'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
...
```

With version 8.0.0, the cluster option is mandatory. Another problem is that if you are using the Laravel-WebSockets package as a drop-in replacement for the pusher, it would be a problem because, in production, pusher connects to that cluster you provided in the options instead. So what I did is that I uninstalled pusher-js version 8.0.0 and installed pusher version 7.6 which does not require a cluster: `npm i pusher-js@7.6.0`

Comment: This method does work

Comment: Man, thank you so much for providing the information regarding Laravel-Websockets. I followed all the steps on both Laravel and Laravel-Websockets and could not get it to work. It finally worked when I downgrade the pusher package to 7.6!

Comment: downgrade pusher to version 7.6 solve the problem for me. the command is `npm install pusher-js@7.6`

Answer (score 5):

Do this in *bootstrap.js*. It works great for me:

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_ABLY_PUBLIC_KEY,
    wsHost: 'realtime-pusher.ably.io',
    wsPort: 443,
    disableStats: true,
    encrypted: true,
    cluster: 'eu',
});
```

You can choose the cluster location here:
https://pusher.com/docs/channels/miscellaneous/clusters/

At the it, it doesn’t matter what you put there. I am using *ably.com* for sockets.

Comment: What do you mean by *"do"*? Add? Replace? Append? Prepend? Modify? Patch?

Comment: What do you mean by *"At the it"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75547305/edit), not (only) here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

The pusher folks now make it mandatory:  https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/releases

I'm rolling my code back to previous version of pusher, hoping that works.

Comment: Hello Curt, I was able to fix it without rolling back. All I did was manually put the cluster location in the broadcast.php file and same thing in the bootstrap.js file and everything worked fine for me. Earlier on I only put it for the broadcast.php and forgot about the bootstrap file. That's why it did not work.

Comment: @JoshuaBognet Can't you demonstrate how you did it? I am having the same problem but your comment doesn't provide enough information.